# Using 'rename' & regex to edit filenames

Tags: regular-expression, rename

I'm new to regular expression, and am trying to use regex to rename some files. I am using `rename` ([this one](http://plasmasturm.org/code/rename/)) to rename said files. Below is an example command.

`$ rename -n 's/\(feat.//' *.mp3` (`-n` option = dry run)

Output:

```
'103 Flume - Left Alone (feat. Jezzabell Doran).mp3' 
would be renamed to '103 Flume - Left Alone  Jezzabell Doran).mp3'

'214 Flume - Sleepless (feat. Jezzabell Doran) (Shlohmo Remix).mp3' 
would be renamed to '214 Flume - Sleepless  Jezzabell Doran) (Shlohmo Remix).mp3'
```

What I'm trying to do is remove "(feat. *artist_name*)" from the filenames. (From the opening parenthesis to closing parenthesis). But I do not want to remove any other existence of parentheses from the filenames. For example, rename "214 Flume - Sleepless (feat. Jezzabell Doran) (Shlohmo Remix).mp3" to "214 Flume - Sleepless (Shlohmo Remix).mp3"

(Edit: [Thomas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/105132/thomas-dickey) gave an [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/286033/172478) pertaining to what is below)
I know to remove the " - " in the filenames to do `'s/ - //'` but how could I do this in the same command as `rename 's/\(feat.//' *.mp3` instead of doing `rename 's/ - //' *.mp3` as a separate command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you seem to want is a *non-greedy* match up to and including a closing parenthesis. You should also escape the period if you want it to be treated as literal:

```
$ rename -n 's/\(feat\..*?\)//' *.mp3
103 Flume - Left Alone (feat. Jezzabell Doran).mp3 renamed as 103 Flume - Left Alone .mp3
214 Flume - Sleepless (feat. Jezzabell Doran) (Shlohmo Remix).mp3 renamed as 214 Flume - Sleepless  (Shlohmo Remix).mp3
```

Comment: This works like a charm. Thanks for the help.

Comment: +1. can also get rid of the extra spaces left behind with `s/ *\(feat\..*?\) */ /`

Answer (score 2):

The command is like `sed`, which allows you to specify multiple substitutions using a `-e` option, e.g.,

```
rename -n -e 's/\(feat.//' -e 's/ - //' *.mp3
```

and get

```
'103 Flume - Left Alone (feat. Jezzabell Doran).mp3' would be renamed to '103 FlumeLeft Alone  Jezzabell Doran).mp3'                                            
'214 Flume - Sleepless (feat. Jezzabell Doran) (Shlohmo Remix).mp3' would be renamed to '214 FlumeSleepless  Jezzabell Doran) (Shlohmo Remix).mp3'
```

In the documentation, it says

> **`-e`**, **`--expr`**
>
> The code argument to this option should be a Perl expression that assumes the filename in the `$_` variable and modifies it for the filenames to be renamed. When no other `-c`, `-C`, `-e`, `-s`, or `-z` options are given, you can *omit* the `-e` from infront of the code.

Comment: Ah, I did not even try that. Thank you!

Comment: no problem (if it's what you needed, you might mark it accepted).

Comment: +1. you don't even need to use multiple `-e` options.  any number of perl expression(s) can be used in `-e`, separated by semi-colons (`;`).  e.g. combine both of the above into one expression `rename -n -e 's/ *\(feat\..*?\) */ /;s/ - //' *.mp3`